# How can I switch a class or improve this

Tags: java

```java
public <T> T getData(final Class<T> cast, final String query)
{
    final Optional<JSONObject> optional = Optional.ofNullable(new JSONObject(getHTTP(query))).filter(s -> s.has("data") && s.getJSONArray("data").length() > 0 && s.getJSONArray("data").get(0) instanceof JSONObject);

    if (optional.isPresent())
    {
        final JSONObject json = JSONObject.class.cast(optional.get().getJSONArray("data").get(0));

        return switch (cast.getSimpleName())
        {
            case Profile.class -> new Profile(<parameters>);
            case UserVideo.class -> new UserVideo(<parameters>);
            default -> null;
        };
    }

    return null;
}
```

I want to improve this code and call it like

```java
final Profile profile = getData(Profile.class, String.format(URL, "data"))
```

The problem is that I cannot switch the class and I don't want to use String (since I want to enhance my knowledge and make it more complicated than simple).

Is there any other way to switch a class and parse (or even reflect class) using different parameters and return it.
Consider this method can return different type of classes and you only give the LINK and the requested data.

Comment: In Java switch is a statement, not an operator so you can't use it inside an expression.  You can use the ?: operator inside an expression but that only gives you two consequent values.

Comment: Your comment is not helpful since i already know that. I'm seeking for a different approach.

Comment: The `switch` seems awkward and not very useful.  I would just have the method return `Optional<JSONObject>` (and never return null), and let each piece of calling code decide what to do with it.

Comment: @Christopher Since [JEP-361](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/361) (Java 14), switch can also be used as an expression.

Comment: Nifty new feature. Thanks. I also like the extended instanceof idea.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, *switch* in java is not as powerful as in other languages. I think the only way to do this is via if-elseif chain

```
if (cast == Profile.class) { ... }
else if (cast == UserVideo.class) { ... }
else { return null; }
```

Buf if you allow me redesign the API, I prefer:

```
public JSONObject getData(String query) { ... }
---
profile = Profile.fromJSON(getData(String.format(URL, "data")))
---
class Profile {
  static Profile fromJSON(JSONObject json) {
    return new Profile(...)
  }
}
```

---

Edit:

Wait, I have a new idea

```
public <T> T getData(Function<JSONObject, T> cast, String query) {
   JSONObject json = ...;
   return cast.apply(json);
}

profile = getData(Profile::fromJSON, String.format(URL, "data"))
```

which is equivalent to my previous answer, but looks a bit more similar to your code.

---

Edit 2:

If you don't like Profile::fromJSON, you may also use a static const.

```
static final Function<JSONObject, Profile> PROFILE = json -> new Profile(...);

profile = getData(PROFILE, ...)
```

Comment: Java 17 will introduce the preview feature [JEP-406 Pattern Matching for switch (Preview)](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/406) which will allow you to do something like this with switch.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel If I understand it correctly, pattern matching in java works based on object's type (or sturcture), not identity. So `switch (someClass) { case Some.class -> ... }` is not supported because it's comparing `a == b`, not `a instanceof B`.